# Parsing error that pops up only after exporting (SteamMultiplayerPeer addon)

Tags: gdscript, godot4

The game works fine in the debug but after I export it and run it I get this parse error.

```
SCRIPT ERROR: Parse Error: Cannot find member "LOBBY_TYPE_PUBLIC" in base "SteamMultiplayerPeer".
          at: GDScript::reload (res://main.gd:28)
ERROR: Failed to load script "res://main.gd" with error "Parse error".
   at: load (modules/gdscript/gdscript.cpp:2788)
```

I tried many times rewriting it and reinstalling the addons.

[image: addons folder]

I'll include the lines that trigger the error if that can help...

```
func _on_host_pressed():
    peer.create_lobby(SteamMultiplayerPeer.LOBBY_TYPE_PUBLIC)
    multiplayer.multiplayer_peer = peer
    multiplayer_spawner.spawn("res://level.tscn")
    $Host.hide()
    $ScrollContainer.hide()
```

EDIT1:
as Theraot suggested here is the code https://github.com/Gioroccovanni/SteamP2P

Comment: This makes no sense as is. Are you able to make a project with the base minimum to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Sure, the project is already a base minimum since I wanted to test out Steam addons first, I'll add to the post.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: On my end Godot says that neither `SteamMultiplayerPeer.LOBBY_TYPE_PUBLIC` nor `create_lobby` exist. I have not been able to figure out anything beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the GodotSteam editor, apparently the built in methods conflicted with the updated ones. I solved by switching back to Godot stable client.